# Having the Reorder Symbol on the Left Side in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want the reordering figure (three lines) to be displayed on the left side of a UITableViewCell, since the right side would be hidden by an overlaying UIView.

This code I found:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for(UIView* view in cell.subviews)
    {
        if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"])
        {
            // Creates a new subview the size of the entire cell
            UIView *movedReorderControl = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetMaxX(view.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame))];
            // Adds the reorder control view to our new subview
            [movedReorderControl addSubview:view];
            // Adds our new subview to the cell
            [cell addSubview:movedReorderControl];
            // CGStuff to move it to the left
            CGSize moveLeft = CGSizeMake(movedReorderControl.frame.size.width - view.frame.size.width, movedReorderControl.frame.size.height - view.frame.size.height);
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -moveLeft.width, -moveLeft.height);
            // Performs the transform
            [movedReorderControl setTransform:transform];
        }
    }
}
```

Works just fine when the table gets loaded for the first time.
However, when cells get "redrawn" (like when scrolling fore and back) the reordering symbol just disappears.

What is going wrong?

Comment: If you add your overlaying view to the cell's contentView (like you are supposed to) and the overlay view properly adjusts its size based on its parent view's size being changed, then when the reorder control appears, your overlay view will adjust itself as the cell's contentView is resized to make room for the reorder control. There is no need to write code that is likely to break in a future iOS update (or be rejected for private API usage).

Comment: Thank you for your comment maddy. But how is this using private API? Can you please give code examples, on how to do it the right way?

Comment: Your reference to `UITableViewCellReorderControl` might be considered use of a private API by Apple. Even if it's not, the code is very fragile and could break from any iOS update. It's never a good idea to dig into the undocumented view structure of framework provided classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep moving the reorder control relative to its current position

```
CGSize moveLeft = CGSizeMake(movedReorderControl.frame.size.width - view.frame.size.width, movedReorderControl.frame.size.height - view.frame.size.height);
```

so it seems like its moving it off screen. Try storing the initial frame and then using that to shift your subview:

```
CGSize moveLeft = CGSizeMake(initialFrame.width - view.frame.size.width, initialFrame.width.height - view.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should go in the `drawRect:` method of the UITableView cell so that it's called whenever the cell is updated.  It should be the cell's responsibility to draw itself, not the view.

Comment: Same effect. Nothing changes.